# This не работает в методе класса при вызове из другого файла

Tags: javascript, node.js, ооп, ecmascript-6

Есть класс, нужная часть которого выглядит так:

```
class ApiController {
    constructor() {
        this.all_languages = 'boards';
        this.all_boards = 'languages';
    }
    langs(req, res, next) {
        console.log(this);
        res.end(this.all_languages);
    }
};

var api_controller = new ApiController();

module.exports = api_controller;
```

Дальше экземпляр этого класса импортируется в другой файл, где вызывается в роутере таким образом:

```
var api = require('../controllers/api');
router.get('/langs', api.langs);
```

Однако при запросе происходит ошибка `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'all_languages' of undefined]`, а в `this` в консоли отображается как `undefined`. Если же вызвать этот метод у экземпляре в том же классе, где он был создан, то всё работает нормально. В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что вы вызываете метод `langs` в отрыве от *контекста*.

**Что происходит на самом деле?**

Даже несмотря на то, что вы определяете `langs`, как *метод* (в терминологии Объектно-Ориентированного Подхода), вызываться он может как в контексте какого-либо объекта, так и сам по себе.

Например:

```
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    sayHi() {
        console.log('Hi from ' + this.name + '!');
    }
}

// Вызов в контексте объекта
var john = new Person('John');
john.sayHi(); // Выведет 'Hi from John!';

// Вызов в контексте другого объекта
var f = john.sayHi;
f.call({name: 'James'}); // Выведет 'Hi from James!'

// Вызов без контекста
f(); // [TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined]
```

Примеры выше показывают, что даже не смотря на тот факт, что вы определяете функцию как метод класса, она все равно остается *функцией*.

**Что делать?**

В JavaScript начиная со стандарта ES 5.1 есть нативный способ *привязать* функцию к объекту. Делается это с помощью метода [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
// Объект john взят из примера выше
var f = john.sayHi.bind(john);
f(); // Выведет 'Hi from John!';
```

Для более старых реализаций JavaScript можно запросто сделать функцию `bind` самому (пример реализации можно подсмотреть, например, в [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-76)).

**UPD:**

Как справедливо отмечают в комментариях, при использовании для определения классов синтаксиса ES6 все методы выполняются в [строгом режиме](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Поэтому вместо того, что бы ссылаться на глобальный объект (как это происходит вне строго режима) переменная `this` имеет значение `undefined`.

Comment: можно еще добавить, что внутри функций(методов класса) автоматом ставится `"use strict";` поэтому `this` - `undefined`, а не глобальный объект

Comment: @Grundy, добавил упоминание о строгом режиме. Однако не думаю, что оно будет полезным новичкам, которые не умеют работать с классами без синтаксиса ES6. Для тех кто в теме, весь ответ можно было свести к одному предложению: "_bind + строгий режим по умолчанию_" =)

Answer (score -1):

Чтобы не биндить, можно сделать методы стрелочными. В аналогичном случае так и поступил, заработало.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).